# Installed SSL for domain, now getting connection reset error

Tags: iis-7, ssl

I've just installed an SSL certificate for our domain, and now when I try to browse to the site using https I get a connection reset error in FF and chrome both locally and from a client. I can still access the site without SSL (using http).

If it makes any difference I have another SSL certificate installed for a different website, but it is bound to a different IP.

We are running IIS7 on Win2K8

EDIT: For the site that is not working with https: I cannot access this site via it's IP address either. The only way I can access it is by regular http and using the domain name.

Comment: How are your bindings configured?

Comment: Well I have my first site (whose SSL certificate works) bound to https, 443 with my first IP, and I  have also http, mydomainname, my first IP port 80. My second website is the same, substituting my first IP for my second, and mydomainname for myotherdomainname.

Comment: I am confused. Are both sites using the same ip and port number in their bindings?

Comment: No, both sites are using different IP's. Each site has 2 bindings, one for http on port 80 and one for https on port 443, but the bindings are using different IP's on both sites.

Comment: Yeah and it's great that the http port wouldn't work again so the only evidence it's the SSL is that I just set it. Not sure why SSL will bring down the http as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Oh god embarrasing. So it turns out that I had set the correct SSL binding but in the binding I had actually forgotten to select the certificate that I had installed. So it was just sitting there as not selected. This was causing a whole bunch of chaos but now my ports all appear open and I can browse the site via IP and domain name.

Comment: I did the same thing, couldn't figure it out! Thanks for posting.

Comment: This also happens if you get an error message when you first add the binding, but the binding is added nevertheless. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953132/iis-7-error-a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist-it-may-already-have-been/19451777) is the error message I got when I was adding the binding.

Comment: I did the same thing. I think IIS doesn't save the first time around...

Comment: Happened to me as well after importing an SSL cert and trying to bind it. Turns out, when importing the cert, it *has* to have the private key marked as exportable or else it won't bind in IIS.

Comment: I had the same thing, caused by an old IP address in the bindings after moving the server to a different network

Comment: This happened to me as well after installing VS2017. The binding's certificate got unselected and I had to select it again manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar issue with a selfSSL.exe created one.

**NOT WORKING**

```
SelfSSL.exe /T /n:CN=DEVExchange2k2,CN=DEVExchange2k,CN=*.devad002.tsosolutions.com,CN=*.tsodev.com /V:3650
```

**WORKING**

```
SelfSSL.exe /T /n:CN=DEVExchange2k,CN=*.devad002.tsosolutions.com,CN=*.tsodev.com /V:3650
```

Guess the CN has a max length I reached.
just fyi

Comment: today you should avoid SelfSSL.exe and use Powershell. `get-help New-SelfSignedCertificate` (usable since PS5)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the use of `SelfSSL.exe`  will lead to this problem, try to re-run the command `selfssl.exe /N:CN=localhost /K:1024 /V:365 /S:{your site id} /P:443`

Answer (score 0):

On localhost I had to change the binding from my local ip address to "All Unassigned" and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to check the "Disable TLS 1.3 over TCP" field on the HTTPS site binding window in order to make it work. This is for Windows Server 2022.

[Link to the image since I don't have enough rep.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrvZU.png)